# Javascript module not working in html script

Tags: javascript, html

If i set the type to module on this script, is it possible to still write inline javascript, like this:

```
<script type="module">
    import { hi } from "./js/disenter.js";

    document.getElementById('connectwallet').addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.console.log('wallet connected');

        hi();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it for yourself?

Comment: It displays nothing when I click the button, it only works when I remove the type module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scratching my head for a few hours it turns out one of my Javascript files had a faulty import, the code executes just fine afterwards.